# Getting contents of specific div element?

Tags: html, vb.net, webbrowser-control

is it possible to get the contents of a tag from a web browser control like this: `<div class="desc">contents</div>` and then strip all HTML characters from it?

say WebBrowser1 has a website loaded into it. I want to extract the source code from it and find this:

```
<div class="desc"><b>these are the contents I want</b></div>
```

and extract it like this: `these are the contents I want`

Comment: what is meant by "get the contents of from a web browser control"? can you explain a bit more?

Comment: extract the source code from a `WebBrowser` control when a website is loaded into it. search for the tag specified and retrieve the contents from between the `<div>` tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Dim divs = WebBrowser1.Document.Body.GetElementsByTagName("div")

For Each d As HtmlElement In divs
    If d.GetAttribute("className") = "desc" Then
        Return d.InnerText
    End If
Next
```

Comment: this return only first.