# Get text in a div that doesn't have a name or id

Tags: html, vb.net, class, text

I would like to get the text inside this code:

```
<div class="js-text-container"></div>
```

when there is an ID, i use getelementbyId, no problem, but in this case no ID and even nothing inside the 2 >< (although something is displayed)

I found an interesting solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20686488/getting-contents-of-specific-div-element) and tried to adapt it to my case:

```
Dim divs = WebBrowser1.Document.Body.GetElementsByTagName("div")

For Each d As HtmlElement In divs
    If d.GetAttribute("class") = "js-text-container" Then
        TextBox1.Text = d.InnerText
    End If
Next
```

But nothing appears in my textbox. Do someone have an idea? I think its because `InnerText` refers to nothing in this case...
I hope I was clear enough.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Try `InnerHtml` to see what happens. If it doesn't return anything it most likely doesn't get past the `If`.

Comment: i tried inner html too, but nothing happend too... Thanks for your answer Vincent.

Comment: Place a breakpoint at the `For Each` row, then inspect the `divs` array.

Comment: Put some text in div, then see. InnerText for <div class="js-text-container"></div> is empty.

Comment: @Sami : I don't think it's his website/webpage. I believe he just took the opening and close tag to not be misunderstood.

Comment: sorry i didn t click the arrow to see the full code 
<div class="js-text-container">
  <p class="TextSize--24px js-text text" lang="en" data-aria-label-part="0"> TEXTE IS HERE < ........... I hope it helps

Comment: Vincent, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `d.GetAttribute("class") = "js-text-container"` 
use

`d.GetAttribute("className") = "js-text-container"`

I tested it locally, I believe you can use it in VB.Net

```cs
foreach (HtmlElement el in webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("div"))
if (el.GetAttribute("className") == "js-text-container")
{
     textBox1.Text = el.InnerText;
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: A reference: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/66677b14-f34f-4d4e-9a03-326839bb536e/htmlelementgetattributeclass-doesnt-run?forum=netfxbcl

Comment: thanks a lot, class instead of className was my error, thanks a lot Sami and Vincent , best regards

Comment: Hmm, I wonder why they chose to use `className` instead. Nice answer by the way, you had written `GetAttribute("class")` in your code so I changed it to `"className"`.

Comment: Thank you Vincent, appreciate it. +1 for you